# Run python script from another directory

Tags: python, windows

I feel a little foolish that I don't know this, but I tried to do it today and was surprised when it didn't work....

I have a directory `C:\test` with a demo script, lets call it `demo.py`

1. If i am in `C:\test` then I can just do `python demo.py`. Easy
2. I could also use a relative path, so from `C:\`, it's `python test\demo.py`

**What if C:\test**  is on the path?

I was expecting to be able to now do `python demo.py` from **anywhere** however...

```
python: can't open file 'demo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I feel foolish because I *thought* this was straightforward, but I have searched around and have not found a solution. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here about how the Python interpreter finds scripts to run? I don't think this is anything to do with PYTHONPATH, as I understood that to relate to loading of modules inside scripts.

This is on Windows 7, by the way.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable contains all directories where programs can be found, not input files. That seems to be your misunderstanding.

Comment: The interpreter doesn't search `PATH` for scripts. You'll have to run the script directly. Make sure the .py file association is configured correctly to use the "Python.File" progid. If you'd like to omit the file extension (i.e. run `demo`), add `.PY` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. The shell will pass the fully-qualified path of the script and command-line arguments to the `ShellExecuteEx` function, which will look up the template command based on the .py file association (e.g. `"C:\Windows\py.exe" "%1" %*`) and plug those values in for `"%1"` and `%*` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH is only used to search for commands. A first way is that a Python script can be used *directly* as a command and in that case the PATH will be used: just use `demo.py` instead of `python demo.py`.

It will rely on OS specific ways. On Windows, file type (given by the extension - here .py) can be given default application to process them, while on Unix-like, the first line of a script can declare the program that will process it.

Alternatively, python allows to launch a *module* that will be searched in the PYTHONPATH (**not** PATH) by using `python -m module` or for Windows `py -m module`.

Comment: Thanks, got my upvote, I can use this is a work-around, but its fairly annoying from a windows CMD perspective, where we don't want to rely on a script being associated to a given version of the python interpreter, as stands i either have to copy to multiple locations and call the given executable or I have to name them .py and change the executable association at run-time to make sure the correct interpreter is called, when in fact we'd also like to be able to execute scripts that aren't ending in .py as python.